# Slow boot for Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04

Ubuntu is booting terribly slow. I have removed all start-up applications, but still 
after displaying the log in screen and taking the pass it still hangs for a minute or two and then displays the [Unity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unity_%28user_interface%29) environment.

Answer (score 0):

## Try cleaning up your system with [BleachBit](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/bleachbit/)